# How can I start foobar2000 when my music truecrypt volume is mounted?

Tags: windows-7, automation, truecrypt

I'm using Windows 7. My music is stored on a TrueCrypt volume that I mount when I log in. Each time I do that, I immediately start my music player, foobar2000.
But doing that manually all the time is quite an annoyance. Is there a way to automate the startup of foobar2000 when the volume (`M:` in my case) is mounted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [Karan answer](https://superuser.com/a/480913/30716), I today started to expand my Keepass script-fu, and especially my knowledge of [Keepass triggers](http://keepass.info/help/v2/triggers.html).

So I created a trigger that is activated when I open the Keepass that contain the password used for that Truecrypt volume (which *I didn't told in my question* - **very bad**). When that trigger activates, I perform the following actions :

[image]

The most important detail here being how I launch Truecrypt (thanks again to Karan for the [Truecrypt command-line reference](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=command-line-usage)) :

```
/volume C:\Users\me\Documents\myvolume.tk /letter M /q /m rm
```

This way it directly displays the password entry dialog, which Keepass can then populate using the global auto-type.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a batch file or script that will mount the volume (see full list of TrueCrypt command-line options [here](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=command-line-usage)) and then start foobar with your desired playlist (see full list of foobar command-line options [here](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Commandline_Guide))? You can even schedule the script to run automatically on logon.

Comment: I'm really sorry not to accept your answer, but I realized today my question wasn't complete : Truecrypt is started by Keepass (when I open the DB containing volume password).

Comment: Oh well, it's good you at least managed to solve your problem. :)